# Departed to vs Departed for

Tags: grammaticality, prepositions, to-for

Which of the following is more grammatically correct? Could you let me know reason for using the favourable preposition (either *to* or *for*)?

> - After having my dinner, I will depart to my house.
> - After having my dinner, I will depart for my house.

Comment: #2, if your house is in the 19th century.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Depart for* is the usual form, but, in that particular case, most people would say *I’ll go home after dinner*.

Comment: The reason is that _depart_ (optionally) takes _for_ for the destination; but since the focus of _depart_ is on the leaving, not the going-to, this is optional. As with most questions about reasons in language, there is no convincing explanatory answer.